# Swift and method prototype - forward declaration

Tags: ios, swift

Exploring Swift headers I'm seeing this pattern used by Apple, in particular the init declaration of the following struct HAS NO IMPLEMENTATION.
Obviously the init() implementation is hidden somehow, since it's Apple stuff, but I was trying to understand how.
This is only an example, but it seems a common behavior in the headers

```
struct AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<T> : Equatable, LogicValue {
    let value: Builtin.RawPointer
    init(_ value: Builtin.RawPointer)    // <---- how is it possible? where is the implementation?
    func getLogicValue() -> Bool

    /// Access the underlying raw memory, getting and
    /// setting values.
    var memory: T

}
```

I know that it is possible to declare a protocol plus a class extension, doing this it's possible to "hide" the implementation from the class declaration and moving it elsewhere

```
class TestClass :TestClassProtocol
{
     // nothing here

}

protocol TestClassProtocol
{
    func someMethod()  // here is the method declaration

}

extension TestClass
{
    func someMethod()  // here is the method implementation
    {
        println("extended method")
    }

}
```

But it's different from what I have seen in the Apple Headers, since the method "declaration" is inside the "class", not inside the "protocol". if I try to put the method declaration inside the class TestClass, however, I have two errors (function without body on the class, and invalid redeclaration on the extension)

In Objective C this was "implicit", since the method declaration was in the .h and the implementation in the .m
How to do the same in Swift?

Comment: First, note that you are looking at a strict, not a class.  It seems that the Builtin.RawPointer somehow takes care of the initial value assignment to the property, which means that the init can be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the explanation is very simple. What you see in Xcode is not actually a valid Swift 
code.

It's a result from an automatic conversion of an Obj-C header into Swift-like code but it's not compilable Swift.

Comment: You are right. I've found that this behavior can be observed creating a Cocoa Framework (new project -> ios -> cocoa framework). Adding a swift file and compiling, when the framework is added to another project, an header similar to what I posted is created automatically. Moreover, it happens even for .h files that are automatically translated in a "swift header"

Comment: so the question now is, how do we make private code in swift?

Comment: @JoãoNunes Access modifiers (private, public, protected) are planned by Apple but not implemented yet (they published what they had after WWDC, it's not completed yet).

Comment: @Sulthan: Still, access modifiers are pretty useless when it comes to protecting your code (read: intellectual property).

Comment: @KMP Of course, but that is not really connected with a language. If you don't want people to see your code, don't publish it and publish only the compiled code.